# Extending typedef struct (compatibility with VC++11)

Tags: c++, stl, typedef, atomic, visual-c++-2012

I'm working on a project with is written and works with Visual C++ compiler 2010 (and 2008). I'm trying to use new VC++11, but I have a problem with already implemented functions.
We already have implemented *typdef struct atomic_int* and *memory_order* but they added almost same functions in VC  11 and I get these errors

```
error C2011: 'std::memory_order' : 'enum' type redefinition 
(D:\_work\wp-test\lib\Item.cpp) d:\_work\wp-test\lib\system\Atomic.h
```

If I catch our implementation into #if statment

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1700
#include <atomic>
#else
//out implementation
namspace std{
  typedef enum memory_order
  {
   memory_order_relaxed,
   ...
  } memory_order;
  typedef struct atomic_int{
   ...
  }
}
#endif
```

It seems that works, but one function, that is not implemented in VC  11 is missing and another function cannot convert parameter

```
error C2039: 'compare_swap' : is not a member of 'std::atomic_int'
D:\_work\wp-test\lib\network\ConnectionSocket.cpp

error C2664: 'std::atomic_int::atomic_int(const std::atomic_int &)' : 
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'const std::atomic_int &' 
(D:\_work\wp-test\lib\Item.cpp) D:\_work\wp-test\lib\system\Cache.h
```

Please help me find some solution ... how to override whole *atomic_int* from VC++11, or how to add memeber to ?
Thank you

Comment: "Compilator" eh? Is that a new kind of tool?

Comment: Why not put it in your own namespace instead of in std?

Comment: since neither the method in question (compare_swap) nor the invalid parameter in call list (second error) are present in any of the code above, I'm going to put on my speculation-cap and suggest the problem lies in code your NOT showing us.

Comment: sorry, my mistake ... of course compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So **compare_swap** function is old draft name of std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak/strong in . It's allready implemented in C++11, but we used old name.

The another error **C2664** also problem of old draft (missing overloaded **load** method).